# Are Harbard and Saga actually Odin and Frigg?

Tags: norse, odin

I heard recently that Harbard was actually Odin. The supposition was in his reaction after tricking Thor he displayed the same patterns as Odin. Similarly I heard that Saga is purported to be Frigg in disguise by some experts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identification of *Harbard* (grey-beard) with *Odin* is a very well-established one among modern scholars. It is based on the fact that both in the [Poetic Edda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetic_Edda) (*Grímnismál* 47) and in the [Prose Edda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose_Edda) (*Gylfaginning* 20, quoting *Grímnismál*), *Harbard* appears in a list of names of *Odin*.

In general, modern translators of the Poetic Edda like Hollander, Larrington and Crawford, unanimously identify *Harbard* as *Odin* in disguise in their introductions to the poem [*Hárbarðsljóð*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A1rbar%C3%B0slj%C3%B3%C3%B0), the only one in which *Harbard* appears as a character.

The situation with *Saga* is a bit less clear, given the scarcity of references to this goddess. The only source of information is again *Grímnismál* (stanza 7, Carolyne Larrington translation), where she appears in a list of godly residences:

> Sokkvabekk a fourth is called and cool waves
> resound over it;
> there Odin and Saga drink every day,
> joyful, from golden cups

*Saga* is briefly mentioned again together with her dwelling *Sokkvabekk* in *Gylfaginning* (chapter 35), which probably uses *Grímnismál* as a source.

The fact that she is described as drinking with *Odin*, combined with the etymology of *Sokkvabekk* (sunken-bank) which is reminiscent of *Frigg*'s dwelling in *Fensalir* (fen-halls), has led scholars to identify the two goddesses. The most commonly accepted etymology for *Saga*, 'seeress', a role attributed to *Frigg* seems to confirm the identification.

However, while one can definitely talk of *Harbard* as '*Odin* in disguise', as evidenced by the fact that in *Hárbarðsljóð* he never reveals his true identity to *Thor*, it is more appropriate to refer to *Saga* as a by-name of *Frigg* (rather than '*Frigg* in disguise'), possibily used by skalds for the purpose of alliteration, on which Norse poetry relied a lot. On this point, Stephan Grundy makes a little comment in *Freyja and Frigg* (appearing in *[The Concept of the Goddess](https://books.google.pt/books?id=oBiEAgAAQBAJ)*):

> [...] but Sága, who drinks with
> Óðinn in Sökkvabekkr, may be a by-form of Frigg used for alliterative purposes
> (though Frigg’s own name is used to alliterate with that of her hall, Fensalir,
> in *Voluspá*). Hollander suggests that the names of the two halls, Sunken-benches
> and Fen-Halls, may be compared, and the verse itself
> suggests a close permanent relationship between Sága and Óðinn:
> ‘Sökkvabekkr hight the fourth… where Óðinn and Sága drink through all
> days, glad, out of golden cups’ (*Grímnismál* verse 7).

Comment: Thanks. The last paragraph was extremely useful and has given me something more to consider and study. Didn't think about the alliteration at all.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I added the full paragraph by Grundy since you were interested. Unfortunately it's not much.